# Matplotlib, adding another axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I need add another axis using matplotlib but I can't get a nice chart. Below is my code:

```
x = company['Date']
y = company['Close']
x1 = WIG['Date']
y1 = WIG['Close']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

myFmt = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)


fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel('PLN')
plt.title(name_of_company)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

I have a nice chart but know I need to add data x1 = WIG['Date']
y1 = WIG['Close'].

WGI['Data'] are the same as x = company['Date'].

Do you have any idea ? Thanks All for help

I hope that this picture shows better what I need to accomplish. Secondary axis is WIG and I need to put in on the plot
[image]

Comment: You mean `ax.plot(x1,y1)` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that the issue

Comment: So what exactly happens then? Note that you would need a [mcve] anyways.